Missing Greek Accents with Type that includes accents
I'm using a specific Greek font for biblical Greek typesetting. The problem is, after compilation, none of the Greek accents are rendered. The letters are typeset fine. But not the accents. What am I doing wrong? Thank-you for your help!
I found this:
Typesetting an Archaic Form of Greek
That seems to be answering my question but the implementation is hard to interpret. What is making the accents appear with that approach?
I'm also using Greek Font Society using Teknia Font.
Here's my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine} % For creating drop caps
\usepackage{yfonts}   % For Goudy Initialen font
\usepackage{xcolor} % Provides \textcolor
% Set the page geometry with default text width
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Add this to use fontspec
\setmainfont{TekniaGreek}[Extension=.ttf, Path=C:/, UprightFont=*]

\geometry{
    paperwidth=9.4in,
    paperheight=6.8in,
    headheight=0pt, % Remove header
    headsep=0pt,    % Remove space for header
    footskip=0pt,   % Remove footer
    marginparwidth=0pt, % Remove marginal notes
    marginparsep=0pt,   % Remove separation for marginal notes
    textwidth=50mm,
    textheight=130mm,
    top=71.86614pt,
    inner=35mm, 
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{maroon}{RGB}{128,0,0}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily\color{maroon}}
\newcommand{\versenum}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{\textcolor{maroon}{#1}}}%
  \nobreak\hspace{0pt}\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\dropcap}[1]{%
  \lettrine[
    lines=4,
    findent=0pt,
    nindent=0pt,
    loversize=-0.30
  ]{#1}{}%
}

\linespread{0.9}


\begin{document}

\dropcap{Ε}ύλογητοσ ὁ θεὁς καἱ πατἡρ τοῦ κυρἰου

\end{document}

The Dropcap doesn't work either but that's another issue irrelevant to my question here.
How do I get the accents to render? Thank-you!

You are first loading newtxtext which selects the font TeXGyre Termes and then later load a different font. In your setup newtxtext "wins" and you effectively get TeX Gyre Termes which does not contain these accents.

If you don't want TeX Gyre Termes, then you shouldn't load newtxtext. When loading Teknia Greek, do you refer to https://www.billmounce.com/freegreekfont?

Besides what Marcel says, the Teknia font uses a nonstandard character mapping.

I don't think you want to use Teknia. If you read the (scanty) documentation, you can deduce that the font uses a nonstandard layout.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Add this to use fontspec
\setmainfont{TekniaGreek}[Extension=.ttf, Path=./, UprightFont=*]

\begin{document}

% Εὐλογητὸς ὁ θεὸς καὶ πατὴρ τοῦ κυρίου

Eujloghto;V oJ qeo;V kaiv path;r tou: kurivou

\end{document}

You can see the text (taken from the net, with correct diacritics) and its realization for Teknia to work.

I would keep at least at arm length from it. It is definitely not suitable for scholarly work.
Just for comparison, top is what you get from a properly crafted Greek font (GFS Didot), with standard encoding, bottom is TekniaGreek, with its nonstandard encoding.

